# In Typescript, what type is LeafletJs's "map"?

Tags: angular, leaflet

I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-and-leaflet to make a starter Angular app which uses LeafletJS.

Alas, I am forced to set

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
```

otherwise my TypeScript doesn't compile

```
Error: src/app/map/map.component.ts:10:11 - error TS7008: Member 'map' implicitly has an 'any' type.

10   private map;
```

The only way that I can get around it is to declare `private map: any;` as my code will give it a type a few lines later:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as L from 'leaflet';

u/Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private map;

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
    center: [ 39.8282, -98.5795 ],
    zoom: 3
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 3,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="[http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });
}
```

It compiles, it's fine, even with the strict compilation option, but the niggling perfectionist in me wants to give that `private` declaration a type, not `any`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using [`@types/leaflet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet), the class [`Map`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet/index.d.ts#L2326) is available. Therefore the following should work:

```
private map: L.Map;
```

Or maybe something like:

```
import { Map } from 'leaflet';

private map: Map;
```

**Edit:** Maybe you could give `private map: L.Map;` a try, even without the additional package for types.

Comment: You are probably correct, but, when I try it, I get `error TS2564: Property 'map' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Comment: Maybe you could try `const map = L.map(...);` and see what type gets inferred. Do you use the type package?

Comment: Sorry, but ` const map = L.map(...);` didn't work.  Did you mean that I should  use some values for `...`?  Also, what is `the type package`? Sorry to be so thick

Comment: No problem :) I was thinking, maybe your IDE suggests a type. You could properly test this via `const map =  L.map('map', {<your-options>});`; Type package: do you use `@types/leaflet`?